# Android Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000040 (code=1) Error

Tags: android, web-services, opencv, camera

I am working on an android application. In which I am getting users photo images(5 images)(Using **opencv2.4.2** camera with face detection) and save into my database in the server using web service. For this I am using Opencv2.4.2 face detection sample, **Ksoap2** for web service. In my android **emulator** and **device(android 4.0.4)** application working fine. But When I check with another device(**android 4.0.3**) it throws **"Unfortunately, Myapp has stopped"**. I have attached my log file below. I don't know what is the problem. Can you give me suggestions regarding this would be great.

```
Log:
I/Sample::SurfaceView(  746): Frame started with loop
I/Sample::FdView(  746): processFrame with face and ok started!
I/Sample::FdView(  746): area: 80089
D/dalvikvm(  746): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1202K, 20% free 7337K/9159K, paused 51ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(  746): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.496MB for 1228816-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(  746): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 7% free 8537K/9159K, paused 2ms+4ms
I/Sample::SurfaceView(  746): bmp.recycle()
I/Sample::SurfaceView(  746): Frame started with loop
I/Sample::FdView(  746): processFrame with face and ok started!
I/Sample::FdView(  746): area: 83521
D/dalvikvm(  746): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1202K, 20% free 7337K/9159K, paused 50ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(  746): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.496MB for 1228816-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(  746): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 7% free 8537K/9159K, paused 3ms+3ms
I/Sample::SurfaceView(  746): bmp.recycle()
I/Sample::SurfaceView(  746): Frame started with loop
I/OpenCV_NativeCamera(  746): ### Camera FPS ### [2190] Frames, 9.10 FPS
I/Sample::FdView(  746): processFrame with face and ok started!
I/Sample::FdView(  746): area: 87025
D/dalvikvm(  746): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1202K, 20% free 7337K/9159K, paused 30ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(  746): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.495MB for 1228816-byte allocation
F/libc    (  746): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000040 (code=1)
I/wpa_supplicant(  421): [CTRL_IFACE]SIGNAL_POLL
I/DEBUG   (   83): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (   83): Build fingerprint: 'softwinners/crane_q7/crane-q7:4.0.3/IML74K/20120709:eng/test-keys'
I/DEBUG   (   83): pid: 746, tid: 747  >>> com.test.mailconf <<<
I/DEBUG   (   83): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000040
I/DEBUG   (   83):  r0 00000020  r1 000106e0  r2 000106e0  r3 409d51e8
I/DEBUG   (   83):  r4 41140d88  r5 40896c58  r6 00000000  r7 000106e0
I/DEBUG   (   83):  r8 41140d00  r9 000106e0  10 41140e00  fp 40822394
I/DEBUG   (   83):  ip 00000011  sp 100ffdd0  lr 40811fc4  pc 40821fac  cpsr 80000010
I/DEBUG   (   83):  d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   83):  d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   83):  d4  0000000000000000  d5  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   83):  d6  0000000000000000  d7  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   83):  d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   83):  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   83):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   83):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   83):  d16 0000000000000000  d17 991f1f1f991f1f1f
I/DEBUG   (   83):  d18 0707070703030303  d19 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   83):  d20 0100010001000100  d21 0100010001000100
I/DEBUG   (   83):  d22 0000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   83):  d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   83):  d26 0067006700670067  d27 0067006700670067
I/DEBUG   (   83):  d28 0067006700670067  d29 0067006700670067
I/DEBUG   (   83):  d30 00308000002b4000  d31 003b40000035c000
I/DEBUG   (   83):  scr 80000012
I/DEBUG   (   83):
I/DEBUG   (   83):          #00  pc 00042fac  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   83):          #01  pc 00032fc0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z21dvmHeapBitmapScanWalkP10HeapBitmapPFvP6ObjectPvS3_ES3_)
I/DEBUG   (   83):          #02  pc 000433c4  /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z24dvmHeapScanMarkedObjectsv)
I/DEBUG   (   83):          #03  pc 00033694  /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z25dvmCollectGarbageInternalPK6GcSpec)
I/DEBUG   (   83):          #04  pc 0007ba40  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   83):          #05  pc 0005f656  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   83):          #06  pc 00012be4  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry)
I/DEBUG   (   83):          #07  pc 00012738  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create)
I/DEBUG   (   83):
I/DEBUG   (   83): code around pc:
I/DEBUG   (   83): 40821f8c e1a04000 e59f01e0 e1a07001 e79f5000  ..@.......p...P..
I/DEBUG   (   83): 40821f9c e5940000 e59530b0 e1500003 0a00003a  ......0....P.:...
I/DEBUG   (   83): 40821fac e590c020 e31c0101 0a000011 ebfffeb9   ...............
I/DEBUG   (   83): 40821fbc e5940000 e5903020 e3130202 08bd81f0  ..... 0..........
I/DEBUG   (   83): 40821fcc e594e008 e2846010 e35e0000 08bd81f0  ......`....^.....
I/DEBUG   (   83):
I/DEBUG   (   83): code around lr:
I/DEBUG   (   83): 40811fa4 e0888404 e16fcf16 e58d3004 e1a0100a  .......o..0......
I/DEBUG   (   83): 40811fb4 e1a02009 e1c66c33 e088018c e12fff3b  .. ..3l......;./.
I/DEBUG   (   83): 40811fc4 e3560000 e59d3004 1afffff5 e5971010  ...V..0..........
I/DEBUG   (   83): 40811fd4 e597800c e068e001 e1a0142e e2844001  .......h......@..
I/DEBUG   (   83): 40811fe4 e2855c01 e1510004 2affffe7 e28dd00c  ..\....Q....*....
I/DEBUG   (   83):
I/DEBUG   (   83): stack:
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffd90  00000000 
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffd94  40891f90  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffd98  000106e0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffd9c  40f9af88  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffda0  000106e0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffda4  4115c378  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffda8  1e000000 
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffdac  80000000 
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffdb0  40b6e980  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffdb4  40821f28  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffdb8  4113fef8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffdbc  40896c58  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffdc0  4113ff28  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffdc4  40896c58  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffdc8  df0027ad 
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffdcc  00000000 
I/DEBUG   (   83): #00 100ffdd0  000076bd 
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffdd4  0076be00 
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffdd8  00000000 
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffddc  0001079c  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffde0  41140d00  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffde4  40811fc4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   83): #01 100ffde8  40896c58  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffdec  80000000 
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffdf0  ffffffff 
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffdf4  000106c8  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffdf8  000106e0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffdfc  40891f90  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffe00  fffffe4c 
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffe04  7fffffff 
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffe08  00000000 
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffe0c  001187aa  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffe10  40896c58  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffe14  408223c8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/BootReceiver(  144): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_06 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
I/DEBUG   (   83): debuggerd committing suicide to free the zombie!
E/PreviewWindow(   87): onNextFrameAvailableSW: Unable to dequeue preview window buffer: 32 -> Broken pipe
W/PreviewWindow(   87): now undequeued: 0
D/V4L2CameraDevice(   87): stopDevice
D/CallbackNotifier(   87): storeMetaDataInBuffers, false
W/InputDispatcher(  144): channel '412a85d8 com.test.mailconf/org.opencv.samples.fd.FdActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
E/InputDispatcher(  144): channel '412a85d8 com.test.mailconf/org.opencv.samples.fd.FdActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
D/Zygote  (   85): Process 746 terminated by signal (11)
I/DEBUG   ( 1232): debuggerd: Jul  9 2012 16:58:08
D/dalvikvm(  144): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 504K, 13% free 8435K/9607K, paused 159ms
D/V4L2CameraDevice(   87): cedarx_hardware_exit ok
W/CameraService(   87): native_window_api_disconnect failed: Broken pipe (-32), api: 6
I/CameraService(   87): Destroying camera 0
D/CallbackNotifier(   87): storeMetaDataInBuffers, false
W/AudioFlinger(   87): session id 10 not found for pid 87
W/AudioFlinger(   87): session id 11 not found for pid 87
I/ActivityManager(  144): Process com.test.mailconf (pid 746) has died.
W/ActivityManager(  144): Force removing ActivityRecord{411a5a60 com.test.mailconf/org.opencv.samples.fd.FdActivity}: app died, no saved state
I/WindowManager(  144): WIN DEATH: Window{41129938 com.test.mailconf/org.opencv.samples.fd.FdActivity paused=false}
W/WindowManager(  144): Force-removing child win Window{4127d538 SurfaceView paused=false} from container Window{41129938 com.test.mailconf/org.opencv.samples.fd.FdActivity paused=false}
W/InputDispatcher(  144): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '412a85d8 com.test.mailconf/org.opencv.samples.fd.FdActivity (server)'
I/WindowManager(  144): WIN DEATH: Window{412a85d8 com.test.mailconf/org.opencv.samples.fd.FdActivity paused=false}
I/WindowManager(  144): WIN DEATH: Window{4117d5c0  paused=false}
W/WindowManager(  144): Failed looking up window
W/WindowManager(  144): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@41192d98 does not exist
W/WindowManager(  144): at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:7156)
W/WindowManager(  144): at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:7147)
W/WindowManager(  144): at com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowState.java:1529)
W/WindowManager(  144): at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder..java:417)
W/WindowManager(  144): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
I/WindowManager(  144): WIN DEATH: null
I/WindowManager(  144): WINDOW DIED Window{412a85d8 com.test.mailconf/org.opencv.samples.fd.FdActivity paused=false}
D/Activity(  338): pckname = com.android.launcher mComponent = com.android.launcher2.Launcher
I/wpa_supplicant(  421): [CTRL_IFACE]SIGNAL_POLL
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You segfaulted.  This means you accessed memory that you didn't have legal access to.  The address is very low, so its almost certainly due to dereferencing a null pointer or trying to access a null array.  The actual crash is happening in dalvik heap.  So somehow you passed a null to the heap or overwrote something the heap was using.

Chances are this occurred via a JNI call overwriting memory that dalvik thought was released and had reused.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This issue only coming in android 4.0.3 device. But working fine in android 4.0.4 device.  is there any other way to fix this?

Comment: Gabe is correct.  In my case I was trying to manipulate an object that I didn't realize had earlier been reset to null.