# Native OpenCV face detection error

Tags: android, opencv, face-detection, native-code

I'm new on developing a native code for android application.
Actually I'm going to test some native OpenCV samples for android. I'm using Eclipse. I found a few errors upon compiling the face detection example. 
I could correct most of the errors by  following [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html)

And

- I defined my environment variable NDK-root
- activation of some configs on Android.mk

The console result is that the libraries .so are correctly built, as the following :

> [armeabi-v7a] Install        : libdetection_based_tracker.so =>
>   libs/armeabi-v7a/libdetection_based_tracker.so [armeabi-v7a] Install
>   : libnative_camera_r2.2.0.so =>
>   libs/armeabi-v7a/libnative_camera_r2.2.0.so [armeabi-v7a] Install
>   : libnative_camera_r2.3.3.so =>
>   libs/armeabi-v7a/libnative_camera_r2.3.3.so [armeabi-v7a] Install
>   : libnative_camera_r3.0.1.so =>
>   libs/armeabi-v7a/libnative_camera_r3.0.1.so [armeabi-v7a] Install
>   : libnative_camera_r4.0.0.so =>
>   libs/armeabi-v7a/libnative_camera_r4.0.0.so [armeabi-v7a] Install
>   : libnative_camera_r4.0.3.so =>
>   libs/armeabi-v7a/libnative_camera_r4.0.3.so [armeabi-v7a] Install
>   : libnative_camera_r4.1.1.so =>
>   libs/armeabi-v7a/libnative_camera_r4.1.1.so [armeabi-v7a] Install
>   : libnative_camera_r4.2.0.so =>
>   libs/armeabi-v7a/libnative_camera_r4.2.0.so [armeabi-v7a] Install
>   : libopencv_java.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_java.so

But when running the application, a syntaxic error raised in the jni file: `« DetectionBasedTracker_jni.cpp »`, at two places :

1-  result = (jlong)new DetectionBasedTracker(stdFileName, DetectorParams);
     error = `type 'DetectionBasedTracker'could not be resolved`

2- ((DetectionBasedTracker*)thiz)->getObjects(RectFaces);
error : `Invalide arguments 'Candidates are : void getObjects(?&)'`

Please see the attached images

- [image: error 1]
- [image: error 2]

I don't understand why I got these errors, since i never touched the original code ? 
Any idea to correct these bugs ?

Comment: In Eclipse i always have like this error, but after close cpp file and restart IDE Eclipse, Apllication successfull run.  Dont know, why it...

Comment: Actually closing and restarting  it changes nothing for me !!

Answer (score 1):

DetectionBasedTracker_jni.h is missing from your project. It is included in general, I don't know why you don't have it. It may cause your errors, but its just a tip.

timurDroid

> In Eclipse i always have like this error, but after close cpp file and
>   restart IDE Eclipse, Apllication successfull run. Dont know, why it..

I believe the anomaly you are talking about may be a different issue, because in that case you have a Lot of error messages containing `could not be resolved`, correct me if you only have that one (a few, not all). For me if I open these jni files "everything cannot be resolved" due to (I'm just guessing) prebuild-linking eclipse bugish issues.

Comment: I closed it because it is not mandatory in jni, indeed I returned it right now, I does not correct my problem!
I really have the mentioned errors

Comment: I recreated another project from the scratch using the same code, I have no more these errors, but at run time I get this error Getting 'Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000010 (code=1)' when the compiler calls the c++ function

Comment: this is an out of memory error, could you paste the line that causes this error? My vote would go for canvas/image storage in memory. Without any code I would suggest you to use lower resolution anywhere you use resolution ^^

Comment: Indeed, the error raises when it enters to the first native function (),
in this block:
 try
    {
        DetectionBasedTracker::Parameters DetectorParams;
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "after parameters", stdFileName.c_str());
        if (faceSize > 0)
            DetectorParams.minObjectSize = faceSize;
        result = (jlong)new DetectionBasedTracker(stdFileName, DetectorParams);
    }

Comment: until the line :  __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "after parameters", stdFileName.c_str());
it is Ok, it crashes after it !!

Comment: what version of OpenCV, and what type of device do you use?

Comment: OPencv2.4.6.1  Samsung S3 and Note 2

Comment: check this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495242/android-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-at-0x00000040-code-1-error

Comment: any luck with the link?

Comment: Actually No, I've already checked it, this message could be a flag of various errors coming form c++ side.
I think that I get the same message, but the problem is not same

Comment: I think you could try to redo the whole procedure from scratch watching out for as many details as you can from OS version to build paths stuff. This is a very serious and fastidious subject consisting of a LOT of bigger-smaller components/elements. You can't actually expect it to work for the first few tries ;) Don't give up.

Comment: Failiure at the beginning is pretty frustrating but it is worthy.

Answer (score -1):

Finally!!. I solved this problem by recreating a new project, then imported the src files into.
Now it works fin!